# Grid based ai path finding with smooth movement

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I'm attempting a grid based path finding to my game. The ai would always teleport, so, I've been working on a way to make it smoothly transition to the next tile with no luck. I also don't want the instances to overlap, which means that I have to constantly update the grid with clear and add. I've been at this for a month now with no success. I would greatly appreciate any help. If you have every played Pokemon mystery dungeon, I'm trying to make the movement be just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Store in the object the cell it should eventually arrive at ( target_x and target_y ). Each time you go to a different cell, do a check on all 4 cells from the object in different directions. The checks are whether the cell is the closest to the target, or whether the cell is occupied by someone else. Each time we check for the closest cell to the target, we write the cell we are checking into a variable (closest_cell). If no better candidates are found, then specify (direction) and change (speed) so that we move smoothly to (closest_cell). If all 4 checks fail, stop moving.